# Nuget versioning for MVC3 -> 4 extension library: to hide or not to hide previous versions?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, versioning, nuget

I have an extension package on our corporate nuget server for Asp.Net MVC 3 - let's say the package ID is currently `Acme.Mvc` and it's version is `2.x`.

I've now branched that project and going to put a pre-release version of the same package targetted at MVC 4 Beta.  Now, logically this is now version `3.x` of the library; however, as soon as I release it (once it's no longer pre-release), the `2.x` will no longer appear in VS' UI; which will potentially lead to other developers adding it to their MVC 3 projects; and deny them easy access to any future upgrades to the older `v2.x` library without using the console).

In a couple of other cases, I've changed the package id to include a version i.e. `Acme.Mvc.3` so the new and old can sit side by side.  Only problem with that is that it's then possible for someone to try and include both!  There's also the slightly pedantic issue that to call that `v3.x` is not necessarily correct; because it's a new package.

Also, I really need to be able to maintain both streams.  I can rely on Binding Redirects in MVC 4 sites that still reference the version of the library that targets MVC 3; since none of my extensions rely on stuff that's gone.

When I look at the public nuget feeds; I rarely ever see this practise of sticking a major version in the package ID, but is there really any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many existing packages that uses the MVC version as part of their naming convention to differentiate between supported versions :
WindowsAzure.WebRole.MVC3
Unity.Mvc3
Spark.Web.Mvc2
Spark.Web.Mvc3
...

"Only problem with that is that it's then possible for someone to try and include both!"

I wouldn't bother trying to block this case, it would seem obvious by the name of the package that both are not meant to be side-by-side.

Comment: Yeah you're right - should've thought about looking through existing packages... Right, onwards and upwards!